# How to convert varargs array to 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, variadic-functions

> I want to convert a vararg array to 2d array, but don't works for me.**

```
public class GridCombinedItem extends Item { 
private Item[] subitems;
float register[][] = new float[3][4];

public GridCombinedItem(String name, float price, Item... subitems) {
    super(name);
    this.price = price;
    this.subitems = subitems;
}

public Item[] getsubitems() {
    return subitems.clone();
}

public float getprice() {
    return this.price;
}

public void register(Item... subitems) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (count == subitems.length)
                break;
            register[i][j]= subitems[count];
```

> at this point I get the error "Cannot convert from Item to float"

```
        }
    }

}
```

> This is my Item class

```
public abstract class Item {

float price;
String name;

public Item(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public abstract float getprice();

public abstract float totalprice();

public abstract void print(int indent);

}
```

> What should I change exactly
>   Please help me...

Comment: Show codes for Item class.

Comment: subitems is of type 'Item' and you're trying to add it to an array which is of type 'float'

Comment: But how to convert the elements of Item array to 2d array?

Comment: Just read the error message. `subitems` is an `Item` array. So `subitems[count]` is an `Item`. And you want to store that `Item` into an array  of `float`s. An `Item` is not a `float`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `Item` isn't a number itself, it's the Object - it causes the error.

Do you want to work with the Item or just with the its price?

```
register[i][j] = subitems[count].getprice();
```

If the name, use a different getter:

```
register[i][j] = subitems[count].getName();
```

Comment: I want only get the name of the Items, which are in the Item array

Comment: Then you'll need a String array... register[i][j] = subitems[count].getName(); where 'register' is a String array